# What does "$\mathcal M_{\mathcal E}$ a set of probability over $\mathcal E$" means?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

Let $\mathcal E=\{\pm e_j\mid j\in \{1,...,d\}\}$ where $e_j\in\mathbb Z^d$ is such that $e_j=(0,...,0,1,0,...,0)$ where the $1$ is at the $j-$th position. In an article, it's written : *" Let $\mathcal M_{\mathcal E}$ the set of probability measures on $\mathcal E$, i.e. vectors with $2d$ non negative-entries with sum up to 1".*

I don't really understand what it mean... is it vectors of the form $(x_1,...,x_d,...x_{2d})$ s.t. $\sum_{i=1}^{2d}x_i=1$ ?

I tried to understand with $d=2$. So I have $\mathcal E=\{(1,0),(0,1),(-1,0),(0,-1)\}$. What would be $\mathcal M_{\mathcal E}$ ?

Comment: $\mathcal E$ contains $2d$ elements. A probability measure has to assign a non-negative value to each one and the sum of the probabilities of all of the elements has to be 1. If you take all of the ways to do that you get $\mathcal M_{\mathcal E}$.

Comment: What just happened [there](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2707370/)?

Comment: @Did: Thank you for your interest :-) I finally understood my mistakes, that's why I erased my post.

Answer (score 1):

There's no actual measure theory in this discrete probability question- the author is really needlessly complicating things.

> I don't really understand what it mean... is it vectors of the form
>   (x1,...,xd,...x2d) s.t. ∑2di=1xi=1 ?

Yes, although the probabilities also have to be nonnegative.

> I tried to understand with d=2. So I have
>   E={(1,0),(0,1),(−1,0),(0,−1)}. What would be ME ?

For $d=2$,

$M_{E}=\left\{ x \in R^{4} | \; x_{1}+x_{2}+x_{3}+x_{4}=1, x\geq 0 \right\}$

Comment: thank you for your answer. But why vector with 2d entrie whereas $E$ has vector with d entries only ?

Comment: You need separate probabilies for (1,0), (-1,0), (0,1), and (0,-1).  In general, if the vector has $d$ entries, there are $2d$ possible values.